# How does Facebook set Cookies with FB Init call in "Facebook Connect" setup?

Tags: java, javascript, android, cookies, facebook

Two part question:

I have setup my website to use Facebook Connect for logging in. In the restricted area, I check if there is a cookie set with the name, "fbs_" under my domain name. However, I do not understand how this cookie gets set under my domain name. Does anyone know what happens with FB.Init call in this regard? (I have not used cross domain HTML file in my implementation).

Secondly, I am interested in implementing an Android setup that uses this web setup for data. Because these cookies look to be setup by the Javascript, I am not able to access these login cookies (fbs_ under mydomain.com) when I try with Cookie Manager. Is there a way I can implement this? Does WebKit help me in this regard?

Thank you for your time and responses.

Comment: Good question and decent reply from @liam ... but want to hear more suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cookie is set under your domain as the JavaScript is executed there, and the FB code wants you to have access to the cookie data so you can use it to call the Graph API (or whatever you need to do with it). You should certainly be seeing this cookie set if logging in with Connect - how are you trying to access it? Is the Cookie Manager you mentioned a browser plugin?